# Type error in application type does not match

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, hugs

```hs
nextMyStates :: MyState -> [MyState]
nextMyStates(s) =[up(s),down(s),left(s),right(s),collect(s)]
    
isGoal :: MyState -> Bool
isGoal (S (l) (al) d z) = if al == [] then True else False

search :: [MyState] -> MyState
search (s:sz) | isGoal s = s
              | otherwise = search (sz) ++ nextMyStates s
```

I am trying to run this but this type error comes up

```
Type error in application
*** Expression     : search sz ++ nextMyStates s
*** Term           : search sz
*** Type           : MyState
*** Does not match : [MyState]
```

I thought this notation (s:sz) meant the sz is a list consisting of the rest of the elements besides the head but it says it is a single element not a list

Comment: `sz` is indeed not a list, but that isn't your problem. Your problem is that `search (sz)` is not a list but you are using `++` to try to concatenate it to another list, which is obviously impossible.

Comment: PS areyou really using hugs to compile your code? (Those don't look like GHC error messages, and your question is tagged `hugs`.) That's not been supported in, what, 10 years or something?

Comment: To me it seems like you are closing the parentheses to early. I think this fixes it: `search (sz ++ nextMyStates s)`

Comment: so should I place search(sz) in a list like so [search(sz)] I tried this but the same error comes up

Comment: @RobinZigmond I have to use hugs unfortunately it's what my university requires. I have tried everything but this same error comes up

Comment: @Noughtmare I tried this and this comes up still Type error in application
*** Expression     : search sz ++ nextMyStates s
*** Term           : search sz
*** Type           : MyState
*** Does not match : [MyState]

Comment: That error message doesn't match what I wrote. Have you saved the file? Are you sure you're editing the right file?

Comment: @Ash_5802: you can use `ghc` to create the file I guess, and then simply check/run it with `hugs` when you are done.